Facebook API cannot see pages in Live mode
I created an app which uss facebook API for post and read content from facebook pages. App was recently approved, I can go live. Everything worked in test regime with test accounts, but when I started testing it live with real accounts I have en errors I cannot explain.

I removed permission role as admin/tester from my fake test account, to test it as external. I can login with it and get page data. I can post on behalf of this user. But for some reason I cannot get feed. I receive an error, that I miss pages_read_engagement permission, but in my business app stated, that this permission is granted and active. And when I login, this permission is on the list, that I grant app with this data. I wrote already letter to facebook direct support, but didn't receive any reply yet. Any ideas?

When I try to login with my personal facebook account, I can, I get user data, but I cannot get any pages data. Array with pages is returned empty. I do have pages_show_list permission. In this case there is no error calling this api, but why I cannot see any pages?


I will appreciate any advice

I have a very similar problem. I have an approved app, with pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_posts scopes for a particular access token. But when I try to query "me/accounts", for some FB accounts, it works, but it seems that others don't have "pages". This seems to be a new Facebook "feature" - you don't create pages under your account, your account IS a page? Baffled.

@AndyWallace I figured out the issue with fetching pages. You need business_management permission to fetch them all. I just got approval for it and now I see all pages with all accounts

Both issues are solved with getting business_management permission

Oh, great. Now I have to resubmit my app for a new permission? Lovely.
